# Cropping UV image

Tags: texturing, uv, image

I'm very new to Blender! I'm trying to UV map a sphere as a number of strips, rather like a beach ball. It all seems to be working nicely, but Blender seems to expect the UV map to be a certain dimension, which leaves a big unused section on my image:

[image]

Is there any way to crop the UV image so that the UV layout fits more neatly into it?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: you can just scale those faces in the UV editor. Press 's' (scale) followed by 'y' (constrain to Y axis) and then '2' to double the size.

Comment: He wants just the opposite, the image should fit the UVs

Comment: Thank you, I think this sorts it. I didn't realise I could scale along different axes so as to fill up the available space!

Comment: The UV map area will be 1.0 in each direction (U and V). The image gets mapped into that space regardless of its size.

Answer (score -1):

See if the **Magic UV** add-on can do it. Still in this case, which is just colors, it doesn't matter as long as the layout has all of them.